Help center suggests requesting disassociation of content prior to deleting your account
I was perusing the help center articles and found How do I delete all my contributions?
I found this line:

However, we can offer one option instead: you may contact us and request that we disassociate your content from your profile, and then request that we delete your profile. Your contributions will remain, but they will no longer be attributed to you.

This seems to suggest that users request to have all their content disassociated and then delete their account, as an alternative to deleting all their content.
However, deleting your account already dissociates and anonymizes your content:

Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as "user123456789") and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.

As such, why would the help center suggest spending their time disassociating your posts, if just deleting your account right away without staff intervention would achieve essentially the same effect? Is the automatic disassociation triggered by account deletion somehow 'weaker' than manual disassociation?
Alternatively, if account deletions worked differently when that article was written, as to warrant manually disassociating content prior to deletion, but not anymore, can the article be updated with up-to-date information?

Fun fact: in many cases, if a user requests to be dissociated from all of their content, the team may just respond to the request asking the user to just delete their account instead.

Also, to answer your question of whether automatic dissociation by deletion is "weaker" than manual dissociation: the answer is technically yes, since with manual dissociation the username is changed to "anon" instead of one's user ID.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog But how much more information can one get from a user ID of a deleted account than from anon? I suppose just knowing whether they are the same author as their other posts or not.

Well, not much more, technically, as mentioned in my first link above. It does make surveying a bit easier, but as mentioned both there and the dissociation FAQ, there's no such thing as true dissociation on the Internet due to the existence of archive sites.

I guess the difference is bigger as a mod. On disassociated posts, I don't have any info about the user using on-site tools, it's just 'anon' (possibly similar to DMCA redaction that only CM can see, not even mods). Whereas for deleted users, I can still see moderation-related info, not only their posts and comments.

@CPlus it's possible given enough posts with the user ID to dig up archived versions of them which reveal the usernames at the time of archival (and in rare cases, the profile as well). I have used this misfeature in some cases to determine whether some now-disassociated posts were from users I'd known to have certain ... proclivities. This is also possible with anon posts as well, of course, but easier if there's an ID to Google.
